# Add a new assembly with the same name

Tags: c#

I found this question to an c# exam

You have two assemblies named Assembly1 and Assembly2 that are written in C#. Assembly1 loads Assembly2 by executing the following code.

```
Assembly myDLL = Assembly.Load(
         "Assembly2,Version=1.0.2.4,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=..."
);
```

You create a new project in Microsoft Visual Studio to build a new assembly that will replace Assembly2.

The new assembly has the same name and version as the original Assembly2 assembly.

When you execute the code, Assembly1 cannot load Assembly2.

What should you do to ensure that Assembly1 can load Assembly2?

A. Run the sn.exe command to create a new key file. Run the al.exe command to sign Assembly2 by using the generated key file.

B. Use the sn.exe command to create a new key file. Set the assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute attribute to the new key file.

C. Modify the project properties. Click Sign the assembly and select a new key file.

D. Run the al.exe command to sign Assembly2. Use the same key file used for the original Assembly2 assembly.

I believe the correct answer is A or B , I can not figure out what answer is right.

Comment: I don't really know from the top of my head, but if push comes to shove, you could always google the documentation for .NET's al.exe tool and the assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute attribute and see what it says with respect to key files and assemblies...

Comment: Sounds like you need a better book. That said: first of all, assuming there's an assembly-signing problem, then either A or B would work. They both do the exact same thing, just different ways. Technically maybe A is more correct, since B didn't mention recompiling the assembly. But IMHO that's implied. You could also just set the .snk file in the project settings in Visual Studio. But secondly, the bigger issue IMHO is that there are lots of reasons one might have trouble loading an assembly, ...

Comment: ... and there's nothing in the question (that you posted, anyway) that suggests an assembly-signing issue in the first place. It's also not clear what the presumed real-world scenario the book is trying to express here; it's not likely at all to be in a situation where you decide to create a whole new assembly with the exact same name and version as an existing one that's in use. Whether this lack of clarity is in how you've shared the information from the book, or the book itself, I can't tell.

Comment: Bottom line: all anyone here can offer is an opinion. If you want to know what the author of the book considers the correct answer, you need to ask the author of the book.

Comment: I edit my post with all answers. This question is in on 70-483 exam.

Comment: E. Call Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers allows Assembly1 to be changed, so Assembly2 must have the same identity as before. The same identity is only achieved by having the same name, same version and same public key.

The same public key can (hopefully) only be achieved by using the same private key. Hash collisions might work as well, but that's by accident and cannot be done by `sn.exe` on purpose.

So, the correct answer is D:

> Run the al.exe command to sign Assembly2. Use the same key file used for the original Assembly2 assembly.

Maybe the exam book 70-483 is not much different from its old .NET 2 version. I found that book quite bad regarding correctness. I submitted a dozen of errata at that time.

Basically it's a bad idea to create a new assembly and give it the same name, same version and same key, as stated [in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies)

> Assemblies that have the same strong name should be identical.

So, there's no real world use case behind it - except hacking. I think the book wants you to learn that you cannot hack a strong named assembly without having the key.

Unfortunately, that's not true, because

a) [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies):

> Do not rely on strong names for security. They provide a unique identity only.

Use code signing (Authenticode) for that.

b) there are tools to remove the strong names and usually it works well if you remove the strong names of all DLLs and EXEs.